# Is there a way to let wysithtml5's link editor let the user add anything they like to the href tag?

Tags: javascript, callback, href, text-editor, wysihtml5

I'm using the wysithtml5 editor, but users are reporting a lot of issues with adding links. User want to add whatever they want to the href attribute. However when clicking 'ok' on adding the link it runs through some sort of call back the modified it..

For example is the user want to add an anchor tag:

```
#moo
```

The link that will be entered is the documents url followed by the ancors so it would end up looking like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/#moo
```

The same happens if they try to add a liquid tag for example:

```
{{name}}
```

becomes…

```
http://stackoverflow.com/84748/%7B%7Bname%7D%7D
```

Is there anyway to modify wysithtml5 so it does not go through this callback that modified the href attribute? I've tried removing / modifing the checkAttributes from the parser rules however this has had no effect. There is something else processing the href too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wysihtml5 is not explicitly doing this conversion. This is the result of the weird behavior of the DOM objects it is creating to represent the anchor tags. Basically, `anchor.href` and `anchor.getAttribute('href')` don't necessarily return the same thing.

Here is an example you can execute on the Javascript console to see for yourself:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('href', '#foo');
console.log(anchor.href); //prints anchor.baseURI + '#foo'
console.log(anchor.getAttribute('href')); //prints '#foo'
```

Anyway, I would consider this a bug in wysihtml5. As far as I can tell, you only need to change two lines in the source to fix it. See my fork on Github: https://github.com/b3nj4m/wysihtml5/commit/c14d746b2b192b043673d97f79f3f61c23908f8d

Edit: concerning the `href` attribute being stripped-out during the raw html -> composer view conversion, that is due to the parser rules. I think the best way to handle this is to add a new rule like `not_empty`, and use that for `href`.

e.g.

```
"a": {
  "check_attributes": {
    "href": "url"
  },
  //...
}
```

becomes

```
"a": {
  "check_attributes": {
    "href": "not_empty"
  },
  //...
}
```

and then you add a `not_empty` rule in `src/dom/parse.js`

```
var attributeCheckMethods = { 
  not_empty: function(attributeValue) {
    return attributeValue || null;
  },  
  //...
};
```

See the change to `src/dom/parse.js` here: https://github.com/b3nj4m/wysihtml5/commit/0ef0dad5f0457266057d7e14df42dafe987bdb69#L2R374

Comment: I'd love to say this worked but it hasn't I'm afraid, wysihtml5 is still stripping out / changing the links. After modifying and rebuilding it with those two changes.

Comment: What version are you building and loading?

Comment: I changed the two lines in "wysihtml5-0.4.0pre.js", a thing to note might be wysihtml5 also filters outs content when you change between html/user view and when it's inialised. So href's might be stripped out too. Thanks very much for looking at this!

Comment: So to be clear, you're not seeing the behavior where the `baseURI` would be prepended to the `href`, correct? The problem you're seeing now is the `href` being stripped out when you provide raw html and wysihtml5 converts it for the user view?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I looks like the issues is two fold. Or maybe it was with the raw html edit / initialize all along. I'm going to reopen the bounty on this again when it closes in an hour or so.